# Reverse search at mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find, concatenation, prefix

I have tried to search around for clues but didn't find any.
Please let me ask a question about reverse search for mongodb.

I have a collection that contain a phone prefix, let say bellow.

```
{"prefix":"1234"}
```

and i am trying to make it hit with value like 12341111 or 12342222 ...
in MySQL i can do it with below SQL.

```
SELECT * from phoneprefix where ‘12341111’ like concat(prefix,’%’)
```

**Is there anyway to make it possible at mongodb ?**

Thanks for reading my post and please have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to do this is to use the performance-challenged [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator:

```js
db.phoneprefix.find({$where: function() {
    return (new RegExp('^' + this.prefix)).test('12341111'); 
}});
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help ! this is works perfectly and it was what i am finding for ! I understand $where will slow down the performance but i think i will use it for now.Hope in future mongodb will add some function that support this with index. Once again thanks and please have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! in this case , i think i need to use regex on field part. Can i ask is there anyway to use regex on field ( not value ) when performing find ?